# Redirect to a specific url with different query params using useHistory hook

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using ant-d search bar to obtain the query value and redirect to a URL but somehow it does'nt seem to work.

I am new to react and react-router.

I have tried,

```
import { React, useState } from 'react'
import { Input } from 'antd';
import {useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const { Search } = Input;

function SearchBar() {
    const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
    const history = useHistory();
    const onSearch = value => {
            setQuery(value);
            let queryString = "q=" + query;
            history.push(`https://link?${queryString}`);
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <p className="font-sans text-gray-700 font-semi-bold text-lg pb-6"> Help and Support</p>
            <Search placeholder="input search text" onSearch={onSearch} enterButton />
        </div>
    )
}

export default SearchBar;
```

Am I missing something?

ERR :
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined**

```
 10 | const onSearch = value => {
  11 |         setQuery(value);
  12 |         let queryString = "q=" + query;
> 13 |         history.push(`https://link?${queryString}`);
     | ^  14 | }
  15 | return (
  16 |     <div>
```

Comment: Did you wrap your app with `BrowserRouter`?

Comment: @BadalSaibo
No, After I changed it worked,
One more question it is appending the new link to existing link.
How to open in new tab?

Comment: Use window object instead, `window.open("/some-link", "_blank");`

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring your function as follows where you can get the "history" property:

```
export const SearchBar= ({history}) => {
 ...your code
}
```